# multiple buttons - single page - event serialization without dataLayer

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have multiple buttons "Buy Now" on a homepage. All the "Buy Now" buttons takes the user to "same" next page (product details)

I don't have any dataLayer on the page so I am using CSS selectors to trigger Adobe Analytics event.

I am using 'show' (not click) and fire adobe analytics "event 1". So multiple time we are firing "event 1" as there are multiple buttons.

Is there anyway I can serialize the event? e.g. pass event1:1234. Do I just create a timestamp or? what are my options to count it as a single event per pageview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/event_serialization_impl.html

Here is an excerpt :

> To use Event serialization, you must first enable it in `Admin >
>   Report Suite > [select report suite] > Edit Settings > Success
>   Events`. Then select which events you want recorded in the Unique
>   Event Recording column. There are three different settings an event
>   can be set to.
>
> **Always record event:** This is the default behavior of all events when
>   initially enabled. All events included in image requests will be sent
>   directly to Analytics, including page reloads.
>
> **Record once per visit:** An event with this setting enabled will only
>   track the first instance of that event in a given visit. Once a new
>   visit starts, each event with this setting enabled can be tracked
>   again. This is an effective way to mitigate duplicate events via
>   browser refreshes.
>
> **Use event ID:** This setting allows the capability to associate each
>   event with a unique ID. If Analytics sees an eventID it has already
>   seen before with that variable, it will not be counted in reporting.

Alternatively, we use the appendList plugin which makes this completely painless. Ensuring a non-duplicate event is as simple as this:

```
s.events = s.apl(s.events, "event999", ",", 1);
```

Here is a link to that plugin: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/appendList.html